# Comparing each element between 2 sets?

Tags: python, set

I'm trying to compare 2 sets of data

`set1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
 set2 = [a,c,e]`

How would I go about finding out which variable from `set2` are in `set1` then output this to another set showing the results?

Comment: It's customary (and beneficial) to show your code attempts in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [intersection](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sets#Intersection):

```
set2.intersection(set1)
```

Or `set(set2).intersection(set1)` if you actually have a list.

Based on your comment maybe a dict where the values are booleans based on whether each element from set1 is in the intersection set:

```
set1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
set2 = ["a","c","e"]

inter = set(set2).intersection(set1)

vals = {k:k in inter for k in set1}

print(vals)
{'a': True, 'c': True, 'b': False, 'e': True, 'd': False, 'f': False}
```

If all you want is a mapping then maybe creating a set from set2 is sufficient:

```
set1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
set2 = ["a","c","e"]

st2 = set(set2)

vals = {k: k in st2 for k in set1}
```

Or to get two sets, for the common and different elements:

```
st2 = set(set2)

inter = st2.intersection(set1)

diff = st2.difference(set1)
```

Comment: Or, with syntactic sugar: `set(set1) & set(set2)`.

Comment: Is there another way to update `set1` to see if its been shown from `set2`?

Comment: Note that OP's items aren't actually _sets_ -- They're lists.  For your answer to work, at minimum, `set2` must actually be a set.  For the operator form proposed by @TigerhawkT3, _both_ must be sets.

Comment: @mgilson. that is why I added `set(set2).intersection(set1)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- Ahh, so you did.  Sorry, somehow I missed that.

Comment: Fixed - didn't notice that the sets weren't `set`s.

Comment: @Gaddi, sorry I don't quite understand.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, True but I like using intersection. It is also a bit more efficient when you have lists.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry I didn't make it clear, when doing the `.intersection` it shows the ones that appeared but I would like to know if there would be a way to have `set1` updated to show this like `a = true, b= false`

Comment: @Gaddi, closest thing I can think of is a dict